# Xsl get full element tag from variable containing Xml document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 input xml files.

1) An Ant Buld File:

```
<project name="project">
  <target name="target1"/>
  <target name="target2"/>
</project>
```

2) A Visual Paradigm Project:

```
<Project Name="VpProj" attr1="attr" attr2="attr">
  <Models>
    <Model Id="O60QwyKGAqACZC5_" Name="ILockXml">
      <ModelChildren>
        <!-- THE FOLLOWING PACKAGE DOES NOT NEED TO BE INCLUDED IN OUTPUT, 
             IS GIVEN AS EXAMPLE -->
        <Package Id="tYTQwyKGAqACZC6R" Name="Xml Files">
        </Package>
        <!-- I WANT TO INSERT NEW PACKAGE ELEMENTS HERE, SUPPOSE A FORM OF: -->
        <!--
        <Package Id="NEWGUID!" Name="target1">
        </Package>
        <Package Id="NEWGUID!" Name="target2">
        </Package>
        -->
      </ModelChildren>
    </Model>
  </Models>
</Project>
```

My output needs to have the form of above, but without "Xml Files" Package.

I am using Saxon HE, and I am new to XSL. So far I have the following....

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <!-- THIS IS THE VpProj FILE -->
  <xsl:variable name="prj" select="document('vp-xml/project.xml')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$prj/Project">
      <!-- ______ I AM HERE _____ -->
      <!-- HOW DO I INJECT THE ENTIRE PROJECT ELEMENT TAG HERE? -->
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

I am passing the Ant Build file on the command line. I know how to put more literal code in that wraps the package I am creating, I would expect the answer at this stage to look something like:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <!-- THIS IS THE VpProj FILE -->
  <xsl:variable name="prj" select="document('vp-xml/project.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$prj/Project">
      <!-- ______ I AM HERE _____ -->
      <!-- HOW DO I INJECT THE ENTIRE PROJECT ELEMENT TAG HERE? -->
      <XSL:INJECT-VP-ELEMENT-MAGIC>
        <Model Id="O60QwyKGAqACZC5_" Name="ILockXml">
          <ModelChildren>
            <xsl:template match="/project"/>
          </ModelChildren>
        </Model>
      </XSL:INJECT-VP-ELEMENT-MAGIC>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/project">
    <xsl:for-each select="target">
      <Package>
        <xsl:attribute name="Name">
          <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Id">
          <!-- NEED HELP WITH GUID TOO, IS TRUE GUID POSSIBLE WITH SAXON HE? -->
        </xsl:attribute>
      </Package>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This stuff is difficult to pick up, but I am getting there.

When I say I want to **inject the entire project element tag**, I want to do it generically, not create literal references to the element name and its attributes, ie:

```
<Project>
  <xsl:attribute name="Name">
    <xsl:value-of select="$prj/Project/@name"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <!-- etc... DO NOT WANT THIS FORM -->
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `for-each`.  When you want an XSLT that makes tweaks to an existing XML, leaving most of it unchanged, then the usual way forward is to base it around the *identity transformation*.  You then write specific templates that match the things you want to modify.  Here is how I would approach this particular problem:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <!-- This is the build.xml - you need to save this in a variable because the
       meaning of "/" changes when you're processing nodes from a different
       document -->
  <xsl:variable name="build" select="/" />

  <!-- identity transformation - copy everything as-is unless overridden -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- starting point -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- process the project.xml document.  Note that we have to process
         document(...)/node() rather than just document(...) as the latter
         would match this current template, leading to an infinite loop -->
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('vp-xml/project.xml')/node()" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- behave like the identity template, but also process the build file -->
  <xsl:template match="ModelChildren">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$build//target" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- logic to handle target elements from the build file -->
  <xsl:template match="target">
    <Package Name="{@name}" />
    <!-- and whatever else you need to do here -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To generate unique identifiers XSLT has the `generate-id` function, but the format of these identifiers is not specified - different processors can generate them in different formats, as long as you always get the same ID for the same node and different IDs for different nodes during a given run of the transformation.  If you specifically need your random IDs to follow the format in the question then you'd probably have to handle it yourself using a random number generator but there isn't one in Saxon HE by default - if you had *PE* then you could use the EXSLT `random-sequence` function:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
                xmlns:rnd="http://exslt.org/random" exclude-result-prefixes="rnd">

  <xsl:variable name="idChars" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_'" />
  <!-- rest of stylesheet as before -->

  <!-- logic to handle target elements from the build file -->
  <xsl:template match="target">
    <Package Name="{@name}" Id="{string-join(
       for $num in rnd:random-sequence(16, position())
         return substring($idChars, $num * string-length($idChars) + 1, 1),
       '')}"/>
    <!-- and whatever else you need to do here -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```